# How to call a method of the viewController to display something new from within a subview? (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am following this tutorial http://guti.in/articles/creating-tinder-like-animations/ but am having a hard time figuring out:

**UPDATED:**

how to notify a dragged item left or right to tell the view controller display something new, how do I call a method in the view controller based on the view within it being dragged? They are two separate files viewController.m and this one...

How do I say based on this gesture
GGDraggableView.m

```
#import "GGDraggableView.h"
#import "GGOverlayView.h"

@interface GGDraggableView ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer;
@property(nonatomic) CGPoint originalPoint;
@property(nonatomic, strong) GGOverlayView *overlayView;
@end

@implementation GGDraggableView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (!self) return nil;

    self.panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragged:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:self.panGestureRecognizer];

    self.overlayView = [[GGOverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    self.overlayView.alpha = 0;
    [self addSubview:self.overlayView];

    return self;
}



- (void)dragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGFloat xDistance = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self].x;
    CGFloat yDistance = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self].y;

    switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{
            self.originalPoint = self.center;
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:{
            CGFloat rotationStrength = MIN(xDistance / 320, 1);
            CGFloat rotationAngel = (CGFloat) (2*M_PI/16 * rotationStrength);
            CGFloat scaleStrength = 1 - fabsf(rotationStrength) / 4;
            CGFloat scale = MAX(scaleStrength, 0.93);
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationAngel);
            CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);
            self.transform = scaleTransform;
            self.center = CGPointMake(self.originalPoint.x + xDistance, self.originalPoint.y + yDistance);

            [self updateOverlay:xDistance];

            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
            [self resetViewPositionAndTransformations];
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:break;
    }
}
```

A way I call the method currently is like so but I feel like alloc, init a new controller is incorrect since this is a view within the view controller:

This is my attempt within the GGDraggableView.m file:

```
RandomViewController *rVC = [[RandomViewController alloc]init];
            [rVC displayNewInfo];
```

Answer (score 1):

My apologies I made a big mistake with my last response.

What you'll want to use here is a delegate in order to update your ViewController.

**GCDraggableView.h**

```
@protocol GCDraggableViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)GCDraggableView:(id)draggableView dragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer;

@end

@interface GGDraggableView ()
    @property (weak) id<GCDraggableViewDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

**GCDraggableView.m**

```
- (void)dragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    //Call protocol method on delegate in order to update ViewController
    [self.delegate GCDraggableView:self dragged:gestureRecognizer];
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     GCDraggableView *subview.delegate = self;
}

-(void)GCDraggableView:(id)draggableView dragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer
{
    //Whatever you want done when your subview is panned
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the properties of viewcontroller inside view. So, if you want to add image into your imageview, you should create the memebr variable for that imageview inside `GGDraggableView`. Add this `GGDraggableView` to viewcontroller.view in viewDidLoad or through XIB/storyboard. Now assign the image to imageView by referring it like `gdraggbleview.imageview.image = pics[0];`

Comment: Ok then how do I say that if the image is swiped left or right to load pics[1] after? how do I create a callable method that can set the next picture?

Comment: If you are adding gestures in your view (gdraggbleview), then you should delegate the method in viewcontroller and you should pass the index of that image as argument.

Comment: Ok so I connected the regular view in the view controller (what I want to be swiped) to the ggdraggable view through storyboard and the imageview is being created in code, now i am trying the above and just imageview.image = pics[0] but pics is undeclared do I have to import the view controller.h file because I tried that too but still cannot access it

Comment: you need to create the method in viewcontroller which will be notified when view is dragged. on notification, you change th eimage

Comment: How do I make that notification call from the so the view controller gets notified? That is what I am confused about

Comment: You're trying to access a protected member variable of your View Controller class from an external class that isn't a *friend* nor a child class of your View Controller class. You're doing it wrong sir :D View's shouldn't know about a view controller's properties, the view controllers should tell the views what to display not the other way around.

Comment: I understand but how do I tell the view display this now since the draggable view was dragged left or right - I updated the question to include better information and improve the question